# How do i change the position of the zoombar in the Nokia Map API 2.2.0

Tags: here-api

Zoombar is located on the right in the center of the [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlhBK.jpg).

I need to position zoombar to the top left of the screen.

How can I do it?

Creation of the map looks like this:

```
ctrl_scalebar = new nokia.maps.map.component.ScaleBar();
ctrl_zoombar = new nokia.maps.map.component.ZoomBar();
ctrl_maptype = new nokia.maps.map.component.TypeSelector();
ctrl_overview = new nokia.maps.map.component.Overview();
ctrl_behavior = new nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior();

map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(document.getElementById("map"),
{
    center: [52.51, 13.4],
    zoomLevel: 10,
    components:
    [
        ctrl_scalebar,
        ctrl_zoombar,
        ctrl_maptype,
        ctrl_overview
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog post](http://developer.here.com/news/article?articleId=95801#.U-zJa4CSwtw) Nokia Map 2.2.0 has been **deprecated**, you should update to 2.5.4

If you look inside the DOM generated by the map you will find the following elements:

```
<div class="nm_arrangeableAnchor nm_middle">
    <div class="nm_zoomWrap nm_wrap nm_left" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0">
          ......                
    </div>
</div>
```

You should be able to use something like jQuery to obtain the node and alter the CSS classes from `nm_left` to `nm_right` and `nm_middle` to `nm_top`. Further adjustments can be made by adding custom styling to these elements.